# Python/Pandas executing SQL and storing results

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I want to do some data analysis on some Teradata DB tables and quickly realized with the size of the tables (millions of records) that going straight from DB table to Pandas dataframe wasn't the best option.

I came up with a SQL query that when run will give me the subset of queries that are needed to execute to get the results I am looking for (distinct, max, min, null count etc), and I want to embed this into my Python script.

The query looks like this:

```
SELECT 'SELECT ''' || TRIM(COLUMNNAME)
|| ''', COUNT(DISTINCT ' || COLUMNNAME || ') AS DISTINCT_COUNT,'
|| ' COUNT(1) - COUNT( ' || COLUMNNAME || ') AS NULL_COUNT,'
|| ' MAX( ' || COLUMNNAME || ') AS MAX_COL_VALUE,'
|| ' MIN( ' || COLUMNNAME || ') AS MIN_COL_VALUE'
|| ' FROM ' || TRIM(DATABASENAME) || '.' || TRIM(TABLENAME) || ';'
FROM DBC.COLUMNSV
WHERE DATABASENAME = 'XYZ'
AND TABLENAME = 'ABC';
```

The result of executing that query is a set of individual queries (30 or so for the table I am currently testing).

I executed the above using the following....

```
results = pd.read_sql(SELECT 'SELECT ''' || TRIM(COLUMNNAME)
|| ''', COUNT(DISTINCT ' || COLUMNNAME || ') AS DISTINCT_COUNT,'
|| ' COUNT(1) - COUNT( ' || COLUMNNAME || ') AS NULL_COUNT,'
|| ' MAX( ' || COLUMNNAME || ') AS MAX_COL_VALUE,'
|| ' MIN( ' || COLUMNNAME || ') AS MIN_COL_VALUE'
|| ' FROM ' || TRIM(DATABASENAME) || '.' || TRIM(TABLENAME) || ';'
FROM DBC.COLUMNSV
WHERE DATABASENAME = 'XYZ'
AND TABLENAME = 'ABC';, session)
```

Running the above results in the following:

```
SELECT 'ColumnA_ID', COUNT(DISTINCT ColumnA_ID) AS DISTINCT_COUNT, COUNT(1) - COUNT( ColumnA_ID) AS NULL_COUNT, MAX( ColumnA_ID) AS MAX_COL_VALUE, MIN( ColumnA_ID) AS MIN_COL_VALUE FROM Table123;
SELECT 'ColumnB', COUNT(DISTINCT ColumnB) AS DISTINCT_COUNT, COUNT(1) - COUNT( ColumnB) AS NULL_COUNT, MAX( ColumnB) AS MAX_COL_VALUE, MIN( ColumnB) AS MIN_COL_VALUE FROM Table123;
SELECT 'ColumnC', COUNT(DISTINCT ColumnC) AS DISTINCT_COUNT, COUNT(1) - COUNT( ColumnC) AS NULL_COUNT, MAX( ColumnC) AS MAX_COL_VALUE, MIN( ColumnC) AS MIN_COL_VALUE FROM Table123;
....
```

Now I want to execute those sub-queries and store the results somewhere and that is where I am stuck.

when I try this:

```
result2 = pd.read_sql(results, session)
print(result2)
```

I get:

```
The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()
```

Should I not be going through Pandas for this operation?  Should I be going looping through a list variable?  Or?

My end goal here is to have a summary (in dataframe?) that shows Table Name with Column Names and max/min/distinct etc  per column, which I get from the sub-queries generated from the initial SQL query

Any help is appreciated

Comment: you're also missing `group by` since you're using `max`, `min`, etc..

Comment: First try to write your column names into a list. Then loop through the list and build your SQL for analysis. Finally send it to DB and get the results.

Answer (score 0):

assume you have Teradata db connection as `con` ready:
you may need something like that:

```
tablename='ABC'
databasename='XYZ'

sql= "select COLUMNNAME FROM DBC.COLUMNSV where TABLENAME=\'{0}\' and DATABASENAME=\'{1}\'".format(tablename,databasename)
df_db = pd.read_sql_query(sql, con)
print(df_db)
#convert the dataframe to the friendly list structure:
cols=df_db['COLUMNNAME'].tolist()
print(cols)

analyse_sql='select '
for COLUMNAME in cols:
    analyse_sql = analyse_sql+ 'max({0}) MAX_COL_VALUE,min({0}) MIN_COL_VALUE,count(distinct {0}) DISTINCT_COUNT, '.format(COLUMNAME)    
#Remove the unwanted last comma and round the SQL
analyse_sql=analyse_sql.rsplit(',',1)[0]+' from {0}'.format(tablename)   
result2 = pd.read_sql_query(analyse_sql, con)
print(result2)
```

I hope it helps..